# Kali Rolling 2016 GUI doesn't start after login

Tags: virtualbox, xorg, kali-linux, gui

I have my Kali in a VM and I don't know why, everything was working fine but suddenly I cannot get into the graphic interface.

I have gone to the tty2 logged in and tried:

```
apt-get update
apt-get update -y
apt-get install x-window-system
startx
```

No success

I have also tried:

```
apt-get install -f gdm3
apt-get install chkconfig
chkconfig --level 2 gdm3
gdm3
startx
```

I have also rebooted, logged in again and no success either, when I enter my username and password, nothing happens.

Comment: Fill a bugreport! http://docs.kali.org/community/submitting-issues-kali-bug-tracker

Answer (score 0):

This was what happened:

My mouse scrolling is inverted, so I followed this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294805/kali-linux-inverted-scroll-direction

I added this line at the end of the `usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf` file:

`Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8"`

What I did was removing it, everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

My mouse scrolling is inverted too but I have not the file 10-evdev.conf.

In /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d I just have these files:

```
10-amdgpu.conf  10-quirks.conf  50-wacom.conf  60-libinput.conf
```